# In Ruby, how to show or print out a function object, without invoking it?

Tags: ruby, function, irb

Say, inside of `irb` if I do

```
def foo
  return 123
end
foo
```

it will give `123`.  That's because Ruby doesn't need the `()` to invoke the function.  But how do I actually print out the function object? (kind of like in the JavaScript console, when I say `function foo() {}` and type `foo`, it will show `foo` as a function (object).)

Comment: Ruby's methods and blocks are not objects. Procs and Labdas are objects

Comment: are you sure, then how come `method(:foo)` will print `#<Method: Object#foo>`?

Comment: That's an object that wraps a method, not a method

Comment: The `Method` class is written in native code and has access to some internal stuff, like the arity of the method, but other than that, you could easily write similar stuff in plain ruby: https://gist.github.com/stoffie/6e6d0f82b70bf4a81758

Comment: That's a method, not a function. Those two are very different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `defined?` for that:

```
def foo
  return 123
end
foo
#=> 123

defined?(foo)
#=> "method"
```

A local variable would return:

```
bar = 123
#=> 123

defined?(bar)
#=> "local-variable"
```

Or:

```
def foo
  return 123
end
foo
#=> 123

method(:foo)
#=> Object#foo()
method(:foo).call
#=> 123
```

Comment: On my Ruby 2.0 irb, it will say: `method(:foo) => #<Method: Object#foo>` and `method(:foo).class => Method`

Comment: I ran that code in IRB on Ruby 2.2.3, that might explain the different behavior.

Comment: that's interesting... out of curiosity, I used RVM and installed Ruby 2.2.3 but I still get `#<Method: Object#foo>`  I am using Ubuntu 2015-10 version 32 bit not sure if it matters

Comment: It is `method(:foo).class #=> Method < Object` on my machine. But the behavior seems to be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby in general doesn't use function / method objects. Oh, they're there: [Method Class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Method.html), but in general you don't pass method objects around in Ruby.

What you usually do instead are one of the following things:

1. Pass a symbol to execute on an object. So pass `:foo` instead (the the caller will use `__send__` to execute the method.
2. Use the block syntax where you in Javascript would use an anon function
3. To see the source of a method, use something like `pry show-method Class#method`
4. Use `defined?` as previously suggested to test if a method is there